# 2005 hyundai elantra error code p0501

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, elantra, p0501

So my 05 Hyundai Elantra has the check engine light on. I took it to the store & had them put the code reader on & it comes up with  p0501 vehicle speed sensor performance.  My question. .  is it ok for me to drive it until my husband can fix it?  Will I cause irreversible damage or really expensive damage if I continue to drive it today?   The auto part store said I should be fine driving it but I just wanted to get a second opinion 
  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine. You probably need a right front wheel speed sensor. At worst the speedometer will stop working until the sensor is replaced.

Comment: @mary - Ben is right, you should incur no ill effects from this. My rule of thumb in these situations is this: If when the Check Engine Light (CEL) comes on, if the vehicle isn't running any differently, then it usually isn't an issue to be overly concerned with. Get it fixed as soon as possible and you shouldn't have an issue. On the other hand, if the vehicle is driving differently, get it fixed as soon as possible ... something is wrong which requires immediate attention.